# HTML Form Class not updating on ajax event trigger

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am a beginner web app developer.

I have a set of form classes set up to take values that I am pulling from an ajax call to .jsp servlet.  The ajax is set up to trigger when the selectRegion form value is changed.

My problem is that while the form values populate correctly on the dos tab, the arsm tab is not updating correctly.  The arsm tab will always show whatever set of values was initially selected on the dos tab.  If I change the inputRegion in the arsm tab, the inputDOS values in that tab do not update.

My question is - is there anything else that I need to add to my forms so that the values are updated across all the tabs when the `$(".selectRegion").change(function(){...})` event is triggered?

```
div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#dosTab">DoS Level</a></li>
    <li><a href="#arsmTab">ARSM Level</a></li>

</ul>
<div id="dosTab">
    <div id="dosTabs">
        <form class="selectRegion" action="" method="POST">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <label for="inputRegion">Region</label>
                <select class="inputRegion" name="inputRegion" class="form-control">
                </select>
            </fieldset>
        </form>

        <form class="selectDOS" action="" method="POST">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <label for="inputDOS">DOS</label>
                <select class="inputDOS" name="inputDOS" class="form-control">
                </select>
            </fieldset>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>



<div id="arsmTab">
    <div id="arsmTabs">
        <form class="selectRegion" action="" method="POST">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <label for="inputRegion">Region</label>
                <select class="inputRegion" name="inputRegion" class="form-control">
                </select>
            </fieldset>
        </form>

        <form class="selectDOS" action="" method="POST">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <label for="inputDOS">DOS</label>
                <select class="inputDOS" name="inputDOS" class="form-control">
                </select>
            </fieldset>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(".selectRegion").change(function(){
        $(".selectRegion").val($(".inputRegion option:selected").text());
        $.ajax({
            url: 'get_params_DOS.jsp',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(".selectRegion").serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $(".inputDOS").empty();
                $.each(data, function(){
                    $('<option>').val(this.DOS).text(this.DOS).appendTo('.inputDOS');
                })
            }
        });
        return false;       
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `$(".selectRegion").val($(".inputRegion option:selected").text());` makes no sense. "selectRegion" is only applied to `<form>` tags in your example. You can't use .val() on a form, it doesn't have a "value" property.

Comment: That's a commonly used construct used to set the value of the list item to the user selected value.

Comment: it would be, if it applied to a list. But you've applied it to a form (or in this case, 2 forms, since selectRegion is applied to 2 different forms).

Comment: also, you're handling "change" at the form level as well. That's pretty unconventional. Normally the change event would be handled on the specific form element(s) whose change you're listening for (e.g. the select). If you had more than one element in your forms which fired change events, you might get some unexpected/unwanted behaviour using your implementation.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, I'll try triggering on the select elements.

Comment: here's a JSFiddle based on your code (I just swapped the ajax code with some hard-coded values as an example). I can't see any reason why both "inputDOS" selects would not get updated. It works perfectly in that respect. https://jsfiddle.net/6kg33a53/5/

Comment: Thanks or setting that up.  If you expand your comments as an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi. was away all weekend. Have posted an answer, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any reason why both the "inputDOS" selects wouldn't get updated. However, there are some other issues with the code which might be causing a problem.

1) `$(".selectRegion").val($(".inputRegion option:selected").text());` doesn't make any sense. "selectRegion" is a class which you've assigned to two `<form>` elements. `.val()` can't be applied to forms, only to form elements such as `<input>` or `<select>`.

2) `$(".selectRegion").change(function()...`. Again, you're handling the "change" event at the form level. Whilst this event will get fired, it's very unconventional. Normally the change event would be handled on the specific form element(s) whose change you're listening for (e.g. the select). If you had more than one element in your forms which fired change events, you might get some unexpected/unwanted behaviour using your implementation.

I've posted a working version as an example below. Also here's a JSFiddle showing it working: https://jsfiddle.net/6kg33a53/5/ . I've swapped the ajax code with some hard-coded values just to get a working example, and I've moved the change event onto the "select" elements.

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#dosTab">DoS Level</a></li>
<li><a href="#arsmTab">ARSM Level</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs" id="dosTab">DOS
<div id="dosTabs">
    <form class="selectRegion" action="" method="POST">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <label for="inputRegion">Region</label>
            <select class="inputRegion" name="inputRegion" class="form-control">
                <option value="1">Val 1</option>
                <option value="2">Val 2</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <form class="selectDOS" action="" method="POST">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <label for="inputDOS">DOS</label>
            <select class="inputDOS" name="inputDOS" class="form-control">
            </select>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="tabs" id="arsmTab" hidden>ARSM
 <div id="arsmTabs">
    <form class="selectRegion" action="" method="POST">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <label for="inputRegion">Region</label>
            <select class="inputRegion" name="inputRegion" class="form-control">
                <option value="1">Val 1</option>
                <option value="2">Val 2</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <form class="selectDOS" action="" method="POST">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <label for="inputDOS">DOS</label>
            <select class="inputDOS" name="inputDOS" class="form-control">
            </select>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
  var Result1 = [
    { "DOS": "Value 1"},
    { "DOS": "Value 2"}
  ];
  var Result2 = [
    { "DOS": "Value 3"},
    { "DOS": "Value 4"}
  ];

  $(".inputRegion").change(function(){
    $(".inputDOS").empty();

    /* doing this bit instead of ajax call */
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();
    var data;
    if (selectedVal == "1")  { data = Result1; }
    else { data = Result2; }
    /* end of non-ajax alternative */

    $.each(data, function(){ 
        $('<option>').val(this.DOS).text(this.DOS).appendTo('.inputDOS');
    });
    return false;       
  }); 

  $("#tabs li a").click(function(event) {
    $(".tabs").hide();
    $($(this).attr("href")).show();
  });
});
</script>
```